# Android getApplicaitonContext

Tags: android

I am programming an an android app.

I have a class that extends Application called ApplicationContext

when I make this call it blows up with a class cast execption

ApplicationContext appContext = (ApplicationContext) getApplicationContext();

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message in your logcat output?

Comment: Which class are you invoking getApplicationContext() from? What do you mean by "blows up"? If you mean that it throws an exception, it would be good to see the stack trace.

Comment: yes I mean it throws an exception, during thew cast the cast

Comment: Could you show the stack trace?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention the exception I get is a class cast exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Android's `ApplicationContext` class is even public, I believe it's an abstract class private to Android SDK classes.

Also, you wouldn't be able to assign a Context to an extended Application class.  You'll have to extend `Context`.

Answer (score 2):

you have a class named `ApplicationContext`? bad idea, since there's already a class in the SDK with the same name. rename your class.

but anyway, `getApplicationContext()` is a method in `Context` that returns an `android.content.Context` object.

if in the line,

```
ApplicationContext appContext = (ApplicationContext) getApplicationContext();
```

`ApplicationContext` refers to YOUR class `ApplicationContext`, then you'd get a class cast exception, because `getApplicationContext()` doesn't return YOUR class, it returns an `android.context.Context`. in that case, change the line to,

```
android.content.ApplicationContext appContext = getApplicationContext();
```

since i can't see your imports, the problem could actually be the opposite. `ApplicationContext` refers to `android.content.ApplicationContext`, and `getApplicationContext()` is YOUR method that is returning a `your.package.ApplicationContext`. in that case, change the line to,

```
your.package.ApplicationContext appContext = getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: I want it to equal my class that extends the application, not android.content.ApplicationContext.  I am doing this to store some custom variables.

Comment: I have this working in one of my programs already and I am trying to reproduce the code in another.  I don't know why it is not working I am doing the same thing as far as I can tell

Comment: you don't give enough information for me to tell you exactly what to do. the best thing you can do is rename your class, and rename the method so you won't have this confusion. if you do that, your problems will become quite obvious.

Comment: Renaming it didn't change a thing

Comment: I am importing my class, being explicit wouldn't change anything.

Comment: "your.package.ApplicationContext appContext = getApplicationContext();"  this obviously wouldn't not even compile, why did people up vote this, this answer is so bad

Comment: it of course depends on what you implement getApplicationContext() returns. if it's your method and you implement it to return your class, of course it compiles. it's impossible to tell what it returns from your code. you don't say if you are calling Context.getApplication(), or YourObject.getApplicationContext(). i said all that in my answer of course. did you read it? also, you are welcome. i'll know not to bother with you next time.